# Do SOAP API session IDs depend on the IP address of the request?

Tags: api, soap, authentication, session

If I login using a SOAP API I get a session ID, is it possible to use this session ID with other IP address without authentication? Does the sessionID depends on the IP address?

Comment: This is possible if the user mightbe logging from a new IP address that has never been logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Setup | Security Controls | Session Settings you can specify whether you want to lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated.

If you have this enabled then a session which is generated from one IP cannot be reused from another IP address. Otherwise yes it is possible to use a valid session from different IP addresses.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience working with Conga, **NO**. The session ID generated in Salesforce is passed to Conga URL, which Conga uses to pull data from Salesforce to generate PDF documents.